# $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$ locally connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $X$ be locally connected, $X=A\cup B$, where $A,B$ are closed and $A\cap B$ is locally connected. Prove $A$ and $B$ are locally connected.

Let $x\in A$. Then, either $x\in A\setminus B$ or $x\in A\cap B$.

Let $V$ open in $A$ such that $x\in V$. There exists $V'\subseteq X$ open such that $V=V'\cap A$.

$A\setminus B=X\setminus B$ is open. If $x\in A\setminus B$, the component $C$ of $(A\setminus B)\cap V'$ that contains $x$ is open because $Y$ is locally connected. So $C$ is an open connected nbhd of $x$ contained in $V$.

The other case is $x\in A\cap B$. This is locally connected and $A\cap B\cap V$ is open in $A\cap B$. There exists $K\subseteq A\cap B$ open connected in $A\cap B$ such that $x\in K\subseteq A\cap B\cap V$.

I don't what to do now. How can we find an open connected set $C$ such that $x\in C\subseteq V$?

Comment: I'm stuck with the same question, which I've encountered in Dugundji's book. If anyone could still help (including the OP which perhaps knows the answer by now), it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was looking at that book and this exercise made me curious, do you know the answer? @janou Gleaser

Comment: @User1997 I'm afraid the answer is no.